# How to constrain Xml content to a specific length using xsd restrictions?

Tags: xml, xsd, constraints, restriction

Using XSD, is it possible to constrain the total text within a Node.
In the example below, I want Address Node content to be restricted to 255 characters.

```
<Address>
    <Line1>Text</Line1>
    <Line2>Text</Line2>
    <City></City>
    <Street></Street>
    <State></State>
    <Country></Country>
</Address>
```

So, if I only had Line1 and Line2 in my address and City, Street, State and Country were empty, then Line1 could be 254 characters and Line2 will be 1 character.

Is it possible to set such constraints/restrictions within the xsd itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can constrain the text with a single element to be a given size i.e.

```
            <xs:element name="Line1">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:maxLength value="255" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
```

But you can't say Line1 + line2 + City ... < 255.